# Python If-Statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I am just learning how to use Python and I am having a simple problem understanding the syntax. My goal is to write a flood function that checks every adjacent coordinate...my problem is that when I run the function, and the first line of the if statement passes, it quits. How can I get it to check through each if statement?

```
def flood(color_of_tile, flooded_list):
    for coord in flooded_list:
        if in_bounds(down(coord)):
            if color_of_tile[0,0] == color_of_tile[down(coord)]:
                flooded_list.append(down(coord))
        elif in_bounds(up(coord)):
            if color_of_tile[0,0] == color_of_tile[up(coord)]:
                flooded_list.append(up(coord))
        elif in_bounds(left(coord)):
            if color_of_tile[0,0] == color_of_tile[left(coord)]:
                flooded_list.append(left(coord))
        elif in_bounds(right(coord)):
            if color_of_tile[0,0] == color_of_tile[right(coord)]:
                flooded_list.append(right(coord))
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want it to check them all, then why are you using `elif`?

Comment: Please do not edit questions in order to ask completely different things.

Comment: If you change the code, we can't tell you what's wrong with it.  What are your inputs, and what are your expected vs. actual outputs?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `elif`

```
def flood(color_of_tile, flooded_list):
    for coord in flooded_list:
        if in_bounds(down(coord)):
            if color_of_tile[0,0] == color_of_tile[down(coord)]:
                flooded_list.append(down(coord))
        if in_bounds(up(coord)):
            if color_of_tile[0,0] == color_of_tile[up(coord)]:
                flooded_list.append(up(coord))
        if in_bounds(left(coord)):
            if color_of_tile[0,0] == color_of_tile[left(coord)]:
                flooded_list.append(left(coord))
        if in_bounds(right(coord)):
            if color_of_tile[0,0] == color_of_tile[right(coord)]:
                flooded_list.append(right(coord))
```

Comment: Doing that actually freezes the program... I am using pygame, wonder if that's affecting it?

Comment: The freezing has nothing to do with pygame. You are iterating over a list and append to it with each iteration. Just try: `x = [1]; for _ in x: x.append (1)` to see what happens.

Comment: You have no condition to make sure you're not adding a spot you haven't checked before.  So, once you get to 0,1, you add 0,0 again?

Answer (score 0):

The program freezes, because inside the iteration you append to the list you are iterating over.

If you want to visualize what is happening, try this:

```
x = [1]
for _ in x:
    x.append (x [-1] + 1)
    print (x)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand what was happening now.